# getting Array-like query string from url parameters list C#

Tags: c#

I am struggling extracting values from the followin

```
https://hlapservice0i/Web/api/Purchaselist/Creditor?
 filter[logic]=and&
 filter[filters][0][value]=John Doe &
 filter[filters][0][field]=customFilter&
 filter[filters][0][operator]=contains&
 filter[filters][0][ignoreCase]=true
```

I'm trying to get that `John Doe` value stored in `filter[filters][0][value]`

It is a simple MVC controller.

Comment: Do you want to parse this string and get only  filter[filters][0][value] value?

Comment: try [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)ing string after [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx)('?') on `'&'` and then the resulting elements on `'='` to separate values from keys

Comment: @DarkKnight Yes, that is the only value I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this..

[**Live Demo here**](http://rextester.com/ZUG98616)

```
var match = Regex.Match(input,@"(?<=filter\[filters\]\[0\]\[value\]=).*?(?=&)");
```

`match.Value` will have value you are after, which is `John Doe`

**Explained:**

`?<=` forces match to start after first occurrence of `filter[filters][0][value]`.

`?=` forces match to end before following character, which is, in this case, `&`

Comment: Thanks for your help and effort :)